# GUI Change Setting Remotely

Tags: python, mysql, wxpython

I have a desktop GUI built with wxPython that retrieves from a mySQL database. It allows multiple users to simultaneously edit the database tables. The problem is the client it is being built for will eventually change the database. The database information is currently hard coded into the program. Is there a way to update the database options for all users if the admin changes the login credentials?

i.e

**Original**

server = server123.com

database = database1

password = password1

**New Info**

server = server456.com

database = database2

password = password2

How can I ensure this information is updated on each user's copy of the application?

Comment: Put the server login details in a config file. There are hundreds of ways of doing it. You should look at [configparser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html)

Comment: But how can the config file be passed to other instances of the app? Will it need to be re-download?

Comment: Clearly, there has to be a single central location for the `config` file, just as there is for the database. These are loaded when the program starts. If they can change mid-session, all hell will break loose. If that's the case, you'll need to call a `central` process that performs all of the database lookups and updates i.e. remove the actual database processing from the code and replace it with calls to a global database processing module.

Comment: Actually, you'll probably need 2 config files, a local one and a central one, for the different types of configuration information stored.

Comment: Every time to app loads it reads the config file - if the app is always running then you will need to devise a trigger to re-read the config file